# Renaming foreign keys to fit the context of a table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

When using a foreign key in a table, is it good form to change the name of the key for that table to make it clear what function the key performs in the table, or is it good form to retain the original name, to make it clear that it is a foreign key?

**Example:**
a table keeps track of users, the primary key is `user_id`

a second table stores articles on the website and keeps track of the author with the foreign key `user_id`.

In the context of the second table it would make more sense to call the foreign key `author`. In the context of the whole database it would make more sense to call the foreign key `user_id`

Is there a general convention that deals with this situation, or is that what comments are for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you have a movie table you wouldn't want columns called person_id and person_id, but rather producer and director, or perhaps producer_id and director_id, or maybe producer_person_id and director_person_id.

I know movies can have multiple directors and multiple producers; this was just an example.  Any case in which a table has two foreign keys to the same table will show you that you cannot in principle stick completely to a convention of using *only* the table name in the column name.  You can use both (as in the producer_person_id example) but that leads to long column names.

Don't use comments. No one reads them.  Okay that was just snark, perhaps, but in general favor descriptive names to comments!

Aside from the two-foreign-key issue, I'm not really aware of any univerally accepted convention.

Answer (score 1):

It is conventional to know the database schema's modelling and designing. Whatever makes sense to the database administrator. Business logic is not concerned with how the database is named, only the results. For the database administrator if it make more sense to rename the foreign key author_id to refer to user_id of another table then do so and notate it in some documents that T2.author_id must exist in T1.user_id. When transitioning from modelling to designing the database (which is where you are now) it would make sense to just keep it simple, but you can change the foreign key names so long as you can remember them (and document them as well).